# Как я могу разделить две области матрицы?

Tags: python, математика, матрицы

На картинке ниже представлена матрица, на которой мне нужно выделить контур между двумя областями (между сплошной красной и прореженной).

Я делаю так: использую скользящее среднее, чтобы области стали сплошными, а затем разделяю две области по пороговому значению, за которое я принимаю среднее значение матрицы. Это даёт приблизительный результат, но во многих случаях получается криво.

Скользящее среднее оставляет такой эффект: значения как-бы "сдвигаются" на определенную величину, и это явно заметно при попытке выделить контур.

Как я могу сделать выделение контура более точным?
[image: матрица]

Вот мой код скользящего среднего:

```
def mov_a(mat, size):
    k = mat.shape[0] - size + 1
    res = np.zeros((k, k))
    for i in range(k):
        for j in range(k):
            res[i, j] = np.mean(mat[i:i+size, j:j+size])
    return res
```

А вот код, который я использую для разделения точек (за 1 берется область, где больше нулей):

```
circuit = np.zeros((175, 175))
av = np.mean(m)
for i in range(m.shape[0]):
    for j in range(m.shape[1]):
        if(m[i, j] < av):
            circuit[i, j] = 1
```

Comment: а код ваш, простите, где? включая саму матрицу. текстом.

Comment: @strawdog матрица имеет размер 175 на 175. Разве будет нормально вставлять ее текстом? Код, конечно, могу предоставить. Вам нужен код скользящего среднего, или именно моего варианта выделения контура? Или все вместе?

Comment: если _вам_ нужна помощь в решении проблемы, то создайте условия для ее воспроизведения. тут еще вопрос - вам нужно решить именно с помощью методов numpy или, например, можно использовать opencv findcontours?

Comment: @strawdog Полагаю, opencv findcontours не поможет мне решить проблему, так как я ищу именно точки матрицы, в которых она разделяется на две области, а не точки изображения. Я дополню свой вопрос кодом, который я использую.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша задача нетривиальна только за счет наличия шума - для избавления придется подбирать пороги эмпирически. но решить можно попробовать так:

```
from skimage import measure
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = cv2.imread("matrix.png")
dst = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoisingColored(im,None,50,50,17,31) # <- здесь
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(dst,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
contours = measure.find_contours(imgray)

ax.imshow(dst)
for contour in contours:
    ax.plot(contour[:, 1], contour[:, 0], linewidth=2)
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И еще: если вас просят предоставить пример исходных данных, не ленитесь, предоставляйте.